# Why does the F/A-18 use external aileron and flap hinges?

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, wing, aircraft-physics, fighter

[image: Some of the differences between the F/A-18A and F-18L, a proposed land-based variant of the Hornet.]

As seen in the picture, the legacy Hornet uses ailerons and flaps with external hinges, and I was wondering what were the advantages of external hinges compared to flush hinges in the land-based proposal.

Comment: [Any picture](https://www.fresnobee.com/news/local/rwuvp/picture36344187/ALTERNATES/FREE_960/single%20hornet) of a super hornet can answer your question. Or do you have something different in mind?

Comment: Sorry, my more important question was the pros and cons of each design, but I wasn't sure whether those little bumps really were external hinges or something else.